# What do you call the sanitary equipment?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for things that include w.c. pan, washbowl, bath tub, shower cabin etc?

Comment: From [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sanitaryware): **sanitaryware** - *Toilet bowls, cisterns, and other fittings.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call "fixtures", but it is a bit ambiguous because it includes every piece of furniture or equipment fixed in a house, which you cannot take with you when you move to another house. I think it's better and common to say in two words "sanitary fittings".

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fixture

Comment: I think "sanitary fittings" is a good word.

Answer (score 6):

For American English:

These are usually called "fixtures." Those specific to handling water are "plumbing fixtures." Those specific to the bathroom are "bathroom fixtures." Those specific to handling bodily wastes (toilets and urinals) are known as "sanitary fixtures."

(Most people who aren't architects or contractors don't use these terms very much. Usually people call the fixtures by their individual names: "toilet," "tub," "kitchen (or bathroom) sink." Sometimes people will talk more generally about "the plumbing," which includes the plumbing pipes, valves, & etc. as well as the plumbing fixtures.)

In the US, the toilet is usually located in the bathroom, along with the bathroom sink, and the bathtub or shower stall. An American asking to "use the bathroom" almost invariably wants to use the toilet.

The only plumbing fixture commonly found in the kitchen is the kitchen sink. Other kitchen fixtures usually include the refrigerator, which is an electrical fixture; and the stove (sometimes called the "range"), which may be an electrical or a (natural) gas fixture.

Other household fixtures include electrical lighting fixtures and gas or electric heaters.

In AmE:

w.c. pan = toilet bowl (almost always joined to the toilet tank and just called the "toilet")

washbowl = sink

bath tub = bathtub

shower cabin = shower stall or just "shower"

(bidet = bidet, but they are so rare here that they may be most frequently referred to by: "What the heck is that thing?")

Comment: Here in the UK most houses will have a toilet in the bathroom but it is common for there also to be a seperate downstairs toilet and toilets in commercial buildings will usually be just toilets, not bathrooms.

Comment: Do you americans still call it a bathroom if it doesn't contain a bath?

Comment: @PeterGreen: (late reply) In American English a bathroom without a bathtub or shower is still called a bathroom, at least when speaking of houses. More specifically in real-estate they are known as "half-baths" to distinguish from a full bathroom with a tub or shower. So a "two-and-a-half bath" house would have 3 rooms, all with toilets, but only 2 with bathtubs or showers. It does seem that the word bathroom is used less frequently in non-residential contexts, with "restroom" often preferred, but there is probably significant variation among individuals and regions.

Answer (score 4):

These are called "bathroom fixtures" (in America).

Of course, in America we don't have a w.c.—we have bathrooms, which include a fixture called the "toilet".

And we have never heard of these "sanitary fittings" mentioned in other answer.  So it would be good to clarify what country you want terminology for.

Comment: I am asking for the things which are not only in bathroom, but also in the toilet, kitchen etc.

Comment: How do u call the toilet room then?

Comment: Never mind my answer and comment. I see now that you want British terms.

Comment: I want English terms, I did not know this differs by dialect. I would like to know how do u call in in the US. Do you call a washbowl in the kitchen also "bathroom fixture"? What do you call the pan if it is not in the bathroom?

Comment: Absolutely varies by country. For instance, I have heard of a wc, (although I mistook it for a fixture? ) but most Americans wouldn't have a clue if you asked where is the wc?

Comment: i looked for a thing to which you crap in the dictionary and it says it is called "pan" in English.

Comment: I can't seem to get logged into chat. Sorry. Never used it before. I suggest you visit www.homedepot.com for idea of American terminology.

Comment: @Anixx - Look at Meaning 6 for _pan_ in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pan); pay particular attention to the tag that reads "British". Then take a look at [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pan_1); notice how it reads "UK". When you see those labels, there's a good chance the word is **not** used in that way in the U.S. This is the first I've heard of _pan_ to mean _toilet_.

Comment: @J.R. how do u call the toilet room in the US?

Comment: The room is usually called the _bathroom_. (Even if it doesn't have a tub, it might still get called a bathroom.) If the room is in a public place (like a restaurant), it's usually called the _rest room_. This is discussed more at [this ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39255). Of course there are several slang terms as well ("I need to [*hit the head*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/hit-the-head)" comes to mind); some of these are a bit vulgar for mixed company. I've heard "commode," too, but it's not exactly common.

Comment: @J.R. but what if you have in your apartment a proper bathroom with a tub and a place with toilet (which is common in Russia, we rarely have toilet+tub in one roome except in very small flats)? How do you call the toilet room then?

Answer (score 0):

In my country if you say you want to use the bathroom, they will think that you want to take a bath. WC is used mainly by Architects. The common word is toilet if you mean toilet and bathroom if you want to wash or take a bath or shower.

Comment: Which country is this? Please [edit] your answer to clarify.